# Prove that $\omega$-limit set of a recurrent point of a planar flow is a periodic orbit.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory, topological-dynamics

> Let $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ a $C^1$ vector field in an open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and $p\in U$ a regular point of $f$. Show that if $p\in \omega_p(f)$, then $\omega_p(f)$ is a periodic orbit of $f$.

I think... using the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem, it's enough to prove that $\omega_p(f)$ has no singular points, am I right? Any hints?

Comment: Is this interpretation right, you have a solution of $\dot x = f(x)$ with $x(0)=p$ and points $t_n\to \infty$ with $x(t_n)\to p$? And because it is in a 2D plane and solutions can not cross, a decreasing distance is not possible if the solution is not periodic from the start?

Comment: The point is regular, not singular, sorry :c I've just corrected my question.

Comment: Thus, in 3D a recurrent point need not to be in an periodical orbit or an equilibrium point?
I can imagine $x(t_n)\to p$ without flows crossing or going against the flow in a section, but what is an example of a such a recurrent point in a physical system?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It seems it's much easier to argue using some standard lemmas leading to the Poincaré–Bendixson Theorem. First, since $p$ is regular, there is a flowbox around it. Further, since $f$ is continuous being regular for points is an open condition, that is to say by taking a small enough flowbox we may assume it does not contain a singular point. We also have an embedded compact interval $T$ passing through $p$ transverse to any orbit segment included in the flowbox. Since $p$ is recurrent (i.e. it's included in its own $\omega$-limit set) there is a time $t>0$ such that $\phi_{t}(p)$ is in $T$. If $\phi_{t}(p)$ is not $p$, then again by recurrence there must be another time $t'>t$ such that $\phi_{t'}(p)$ is in that segment of $T$ that is strictly between $\phi_{t}(p)$ and $p$, which is impossible.